# Database Design Deleting parent and his children in nested Parent-child situation

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, parent-child

In Oracle I have a table called Category  consisting of three columns:
 ID = which is system produced unique key ,
 Catgeory_name = which is 300 char , 
and parent_id  = which either could be -1 which means no parent for this category, or it could be a value from the ID column described earlier as the parent_id.

The problem is when I delete a category who is a parent, I need to automatically delete all the children as well.  My question is : Does SQL provide any means to do this automatically or should I take care of it in my upper layer langugae which is C#.

For example if there was a foreign key situation between two tables, I know SQL provides ON DELETE CASCADE to delete the dependent records as well as the parent record upon a delete request for the origianal record.

However, I don't know of any way in SQL that would take care of the above situation automatically, meaning when the parent is deleted in the above table, all the children get deleted as well.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `parent_id` was set to `NULL` if there was no parent, you could define a foreign key on `category` that referenced the primary key in `category`

```
SQL> create table category (
  2    id number primary key,
  3    category_name varchar2(300),
  4    parent_id number references category( id )
  5  );

Table created.
```

You could then declare that foreign key constraint to automatically delete the children when the parent row is deleted.

If you really want to use a magic value of -1 to indicate the absence of a parent rather than using a proper `NULL`, you could potentially insert a row into the `category` table with an `id` of -1 and then create the foreign key constraint.  But that is much less elegant than using a `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I have been trying to test it but I am having trouble figuring out how to pass a NULL in C# so that it still is a NULL in DB. If you know what I mean? So, I have not been able to try out your answer but it seems to me that it is correct. if you know the answer to this question I would highly appreciate that too. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1298925 - How are you passing parameters in C#?  What API are you using?  Realistically, you may want to create a new question to address this problem since it seems unrelated to to this question.